# Exception when trying to run/debug spring boot example from intelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Getting a classnotfound exception when trying to run a spring boot example from intelliJ.

I imported one of the 'Getting started guides' from spring.io, specially https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git project into IntelliJ.

I can successfully, build and run the project using ./gradle build and ./gradle bootRun

Now I want to run or debug from IntelliJ,I get following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

I am trying to run/debug after creating a simple configuration but it throws this exception. How does intelliJ resolve the dependencies. This works from command line when I use gradle bootRun.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Comment: What steps did you take to "import" it?

Comment: What intellij and gradle version do you use. 
You should try to [delegate build and run actions to gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#import_gradle_module).

Comment: I imported an exiting project (spring boot example, gs-rest-service) using gradle. I used gradle wrapper.

Comment: Thank you chrylis and peter. I was able to get around this issue by adding a new gradle configuration with the 'bootRun' task. Initially I was using a spring boot configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this error by using a new gradle configuration with the 'bootRun' task (in the Run/debug configurations dialog)
Initially I had created a spring boot configuration.